# Impossible to inject Slick DatabaseConfigProvider in scaldi and play 2.5

Tags: playback, slick-3.0, scaldi

I'm having a issue to inject the slick DatabaseConfigProvider in Scaldi. It was working fine in play 2.4 but I had to migrate to 2.5.

Here is my configuration :

- play 2.5.3
- scaldi-play 0.5.15
- play-slick 2.0.0

My application-conf:

```
slick.dbs.devpostgres.driver="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$" # You must provide the required Slick driver!
slick.dbs.devpostgres.db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
slick.dbs.devpostgres.db.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test"
slick.dbs.devpostgres.db.user=postgres
slick.dbs.devpostgres.db.password="pwd"

play.application.loader = scaldi.play.ScaldiApplicationLoader

play.modules {
  enabled += modules.ApplicationModule
  enabled += scaldi.play.ControllerInjector
}
```

My Scaldi ApplicationModule :

```
class ApplicationModule extends Module {
    binding to new ObjectDao
    binding to new UserDao
    bind[DatabaseConfig[_]] to DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]("devpostgres")(inject[Application])
}
```

My ObjectDao extended by my UserDao class:

```
class ObjectDao(implicit inj: Injector) extends Injectable {
  // Using the same database connection for every DAO extending this class
  val dbConfig = inject[DatabaseConfigProvider].get[JdbcProfile]
  val db = dbConfig.db
}
```

And finally, my UserDao :

```
class UserDao(implicit inj: Injector) extends ObjectDao {

  import dbConfig.driver.api._

  private val users = TableQuery[UserTable]

  ...
}
```

Error while starting the application :

```
Unexpected exception
InjectException: No binding found with following identifiers:
  * TypeTagIdentifier(play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider)
No source available, here is the exception stack trace:
->scaldi.InjectException: No binding found with following identifiers:
  * TypeTagIdentifier(play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider)
     scaldi.Injectable$class.noBindingFound(Injectable.scala:180)
     dao.ObjectDao.noBindingFound(ObjectDao.scala:7)
     scaldi.Injectable$$anonfun$inject$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Injectable.scala:45)
     scaldi.Injectable$$anonfun$inject$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Injectable.scala:45)
     scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
     scaldi.Injectable$class.injectWithDefault(Injectable.scala:152)
     dao.ObjectDao.injectWithDefault(ObjectDao.scala:7)
     scaldi.Injectable$$anonfun$inject$1.apply(Injectable.scala:45)
     scaldi.Injectable$$anonfun$inject$1.apply(Injectable.scala:45)
     scaldi.util.Util$WorkflowHelper$.$bar$greater$extension(Util.scala:7)
     scaldi.Injectable$class.inject(Injectable.scala:45)
     dao.ObjectDao.inject(ObjectDao.scala:7)
     dao.ObjectDao.(ObjectDao.scala:9)
     dao.UserDao.(AdminRepo.scala:13)
     modules.ApplicationModule$$anonfun$3.apply(ApplicationModule.scala:64)
     modules.ApplicationModule$$anonfun$3.apply(ApplicationModule.scala:64)
     scaldi.LazyBinding$$anonfun$target$2.apply(Binding.scala:180)
     scaldi.LazyBinding$$anonfun$target$2.apply(Binding.scala:180)
     scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
     scaldi.LazyBinding.target$lzycompute(Binding.scala:180)
     scaldi.LazyBinding.target(Binding.scala:180)
     scaldi.LazyBinding.get(Binding.scala:196)
     scaldi.Binding$$anon$1.get(Binding.scala:66)
     scaldi.Injectable$$anonfun$injectWithDefault$1.apply(Injectable.scala:152)
     scaldi.Injectable$$anonfun$injectWithDefault$1.apply(Injectable.scala:152)
     scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:171)
     scaldi.Injectable$class.injectWithDefault(Injectable.scala:152)
     controllers.Application.injectWithDefault(Application.scala:16)
     scaldi.Injectable$$anonfun$inject$1.apply(Injectable.scala:45)
     scaldi.Injectable$$anonfun$inject$1.apply(Injectable.scala:45)
     scaldi.util.Util$WorkflowHelper$.$bar$greater$extension(Util.scala:7)
     scaldi.Injectable$class.inject(Injectable.scala:45)
     controllers.Application.inject(Application.scala:16)
     controllers.Application.(Application.scala:18)
     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
     java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
     scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$JavaVanillaMethodMirror1.jinvokeraw(JavaMirrors.scala:374)
     scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$JavaMethodMirror.jinvoke(JavaMirrors.scala:339)
     scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$JavaVanillaMethodMirror.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:355)
     scaldi.play.ControllerInjector$$anonfun$4.apply(ControllerInjector.scala:62)
     scaldi.play.ControllerInjector$$anonfun$4.apply(ControllerInjector.scala:53)
     scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
     scaldi.play.ControllerInjector.scaldi$play$ControllerInjector$$createBinding(ControllerInjector.scala:53)
     scaldi.play.ControllerInjector$$anonfun$getBindingInternal$3$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ControllerInjector.scala:33)
     scaldi.play.ControllerInjector$$anonfun$getBindingInternal$3$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ControllerInjector.scala:32)
     scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
     scaldi.play.ControllerInjector$$anonfun$getBindingInternal$3.apply(ControllerInjector.scala:32)
     scaldi.play.ControllerInjector$$anonfun$getBindingInternal$3.apply(ControllerInjector.scala:31)
     scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
     scaldi.play.ControllerInjector.getBindingInternal(ControllerInjector.scala:30)
     scaldi.MutableInjectorAggregation$$anonfun$getBindingInternal$2.apply(Injector.scala:85)
     scaldi.MutableInjectorAggregation$$anonfun$getBindingInternal$2.apply(Injector.scala:84)
     scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:370)
     scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.collectFirst(TraversableOnce.scala:143)
     scala.collection.SeqViewLike$AbstractTransformed.collectFirst(SeqViewLike.scala:37)
     scaldi.MutableInjectorAggregation.getBindingInternal(Injector.scala:87)
     scaldi.InjectorWithLifecycle$$anonfun$getBinding$3.apply(Injector.scala:170)
     scaldi.InjectorWithLifecycle$$anonfun$getBinding$3.apply(Injector.scala:170)
     scaldi.util.Util$WorkflowHelper$.$bar$greater$extension(Util.scala:7)
     scaldi.InjectorWithLifecycle$class.getBinding(Injector.scala:170)
     scaldi.MutableInjectorAggregation.getBinding(Injector.scala:78)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding.scaldi$jsr330$AnnotationBinding$$injectSymbol(AnnotationBinding.scala:171)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding$$anonfun$22.apply(AnnotationBinding.scala:132)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding$$anonfun$22.apply(AnnotationBinding.scala:132)
     scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:277)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding.scaldi$jsr330$AnnotationBinding$$createNewInstance(AnnotationBinding.scala:132)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnnotationBinding.scala:41)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnnotationBinding.scala:41)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding.initNewInstance(AnnotationBinding.scala:119)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding.getInstance(AnnotationBinding.scala:111)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding.get(AnnotationBinding.scala:85)
     scaldi.Binding$$anon$1.get(Binding.scala:66)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiInjector$$anonfun$scaldi$play$ScaldiInjector$$getActualBinding$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ScaldiInjector.scala:42)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiInjector$$anonfun$scaldi$play$ScaldiInjector$$getActualBinding$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ScaldiInjector.scala:42)
     scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiInjector$$anonfun$scaldi$play$ScaldiInjector$$getActualBinding$1.apply(ScaldiInjector.scala:42)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiInjector$$anonfun$scaldi$play$ScaldiInjector$$getActualBinding$1.apply(ScaldiInjector.scala:38)
     play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiInjector.scaldi$play$ScaldiInjector$$getActualBinding(ScaldiInjector.scala:38)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiInjector$$anonfun$instanceOf$1.apply(ScaldiInjector.scala:23)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiInjector$$anonfun$instanceOf$1.apply(ScaldiInjector.scala:22)
     scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiInjector.instanceOf(ScaldiInjector.scala:22)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiInjector.instanceOf(ScaldiInjector.scala:18)
     play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$$anonfun$2.apply(BuiltinModule.scala:82)
     play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$$anonfun$2.apply(BuiltinModule.scala:82)
     scala.Option.fold(Option.scala:158)
     play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get$lzycompute(BuiltinModule.scala:82)
     play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get(BuiltinModule.scala:78)
     play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get(BuiltinModule.scala:77)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiBuilder$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(ScaldiBuilder.scala:227)
     scaldi.ProviderBinding.target(Binding.scala:217)
     scaldi.ProviderBinding.get(Binding.scala:223)
     scaldi.ProviderBinding.get(Binding.scala:213)
     scaldi.Binding$$anon$1.get(Binding.scala:66)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding$$anonfun$scaldi$jsr330$AnnotationBinding$$injectSymbol$2.apply(AnnotationBinding.scala:171)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding$$anonfun$scaldi$jsr330$AnnotationBinding$$injectSymbol$2.apply(AnnotationBinding.scala:171)
     scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:171)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding.scaldi$jsr330$AnnotationBinding$$injectSymbol(AnnotationBinding.scala:171)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding$$anonfun$22.apply(AnnotationBinding.scala:132)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding$$anonfun$22.apply(AnnotationBinding.scala:132)
     scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:273)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding.scaldi$jsr330$AnnotationBinding$$createNewInstance(AnnotationBinding.scala:132)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnnotationBinding.scala:41)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnnotationBinding.scala:41)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding.initNewInstance(AnnotationBinding.scala:119)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding.getInstance(AnnotationBinding.scala:111)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding.get(AnnotationBinding.scala:85)
     scaldi.Binding$$anon$1.get(Binding.scala:66)
     scaldi.Injectable$$anonfun$injectWithDefault$1.apply(Injectable.scala:152)
     scaldi.Injectable$$anonfun$injectWithDefault$1.apply(Injectable.scala:152)
     scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:171)
     scaldi.Injectable$class.injectWithDefault(Injectable.scala:152)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiBuilder$.injectWithDefault(ScaldiBuilder.scala:128)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiBuilder$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(ScaldiBuilder.scala:240)
     scaldi.ProviderBinding.target(Binding.scala:217)
     scaldi.ProviderBinding.get(Binding.scala:223)
     scaldi.ProviderBinding.get(Binding.scala:213)
     scaldi.Binding$$anon$1.get(Binding.scala:66)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding$$anonfun$scaldi$jsr330$AnnotationBinding$$injectSymbol$2.apply(AnnotationBinding.scala:171)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding$$anonfun$scaldi$jsr330$AnnotationBinding$$injectSymbol$2.apply(AnnotationBinding.scala:171)
     scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:171)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding.scaldi$jsr330$AnnotationBinding$$injectSymbol(AnnotationBinding.scala:171)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding$$anonfun$22.apply(AnnotationBinding.scala:132)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding$$anonfun$22.apply(AnnotationBinding.scala:132)
     scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:277)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding.scaldi$jsr330$AnnotationBinding$$createNewInstance(AnnotationBinding.scala:132)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnnotationBinding.scala:41)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnnotationBinding.scala:41)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding.initNewInstance(AnnotationBinding.scala:119)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding.getInstance(AnnotationBinding.scala:111)
     scaldi.jsr330.AnnotationBinding.get(AnnotationBinding.scala:85)
     scaldi.Binding$$anon$1.get(Binding.scala:66)
     scaldi.Injectable$$anonfun$injectWithDefault$1.apply(Injectable.scala:152)
     scaldi.Injectable$$anonfun$injectWithDefault$1.apply(Injectable.scala:152)
     scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:171)
     scaldi.Injectable$class.injectWithDefault(Injectable.scala:152)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiBuilder$.injectWithDefault(ScaldiBuilder.scala:128)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiBuilder$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(ScaldiBuilder.scala:240)
     scaldi.ProviderBinding.target(Binding.scala:217)
     scaldi.ProviderBinding.get(Binding.scala:223)
     scaldi.ProviderBinding.get(Binding.scala:213)
     scaldi.Binding$$anon$1.get(Binding.scala:66)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiInjector$$anonfun$scaldi$play$ScaldiInjector$$getActualBinding$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ScaldiInjector.scala:42)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiInjector$$anonfun$scaldi$play$ScaldiInjector$$getActualBinding$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ScaldiInjector.scala:42)
     scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiInjector$$anonfun$scaldi$play$ScaldiInjector$$getActualBinding$1.apply(ScaldiInjector.scala:42)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiInjector$$anonfun$scaldi$play$ScaldiInjector$$getActualBinding$1.apply(ScaldiInjector.scala:38)
     play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiInjector.scaldi$play$ScaldiInjector$$getActualBinding(ScaldiInjector.scala:38)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiInjector$$anonfun$instanceOf$1.apply(ScaldiInjector.scala:23)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiInjector$$anonfun$instanceOf$1.apply(ScaldiInjector.scala:22)
     scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiInjector.instanceOf(ScaldiInjector.scala:22)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiInjector.instanceOf(ScaldiInjector.scala:18)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiInjector.instanceOf(ScaldiInjector.scala:15)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiApplicationBuilder.build(ScaldiApplicationBuilder.scala:88)
     scaldi.play.ScaldiApplicationLoader.load(ScaldiApplicationLoader.scala:19)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:158)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:155)
     play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:155)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:126)
     scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:126)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:124)
     scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:124)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:116)
     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

Am I missing something here ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Much appreciated !

Comment: In general the config looks correct to me. Maybe this recent issue can help you: https://github.com/scaldi/scaldi-play/issues/29. If you are injecting `inject[DatabaseConfigProvider].get[JdbcProfile]` then i think you don't need to bind `bind[DatabaseConfig[_]]`, but if you bind it, then you need to provide the fill type signature: `bind[DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile]]`. May this is the reason why it stopped working?